# The audio files downloaded, file not found in phone

Tags: iphone, whatsapp.app

The audio files which get downloaded in WhatsApp where does it go? Can I see it visually on my iPhone? 
Every time I have to scroll down to play back the audio sent by the user.

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: There's a method here - https://7labs.heypub.com/mobile/export-save-whatsapp-audio.html but it requires an app purchase.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I would love if i dont need to download an app to see it, is there any way?

Comment: presumably, if there was a cheaper way, the linked method would have mentioned it, or there would be other methods on Google